# Change data-action of button by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've made a like button with ajax and php. Everything is working, but I would like to change the "data-action" when I click the button.
So when the like is on my db, I've got:

```
<button id="btn" data-action="unlike" data-id="post-id">font awesome -> heart</button>
```

When the like isn't in my db, I've got:

```
<button id="btn" data-action="like" data-id="post-id">font awesome -> heart-o</button>
```

This is my js:

```
$('[data-id]').on('click', function(){
    var newsid = $(this).data('id'); 
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    var i;
    buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    actionid = $(this).attr('data-action');
    output = "";
    
    function buttonHeart(){
        $("[data-id='"+buttonid+"'").addClass("svEFan");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("[data-id='"+buttonid+"'").removeClass("svEFan");
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/recipes/actions-recipe',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'action': action, 'newsid': newsid},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            if(data.type == "error"){
                output = "Error: "+data.text;
            }else{
                //like
                if(action == "like"){
                    buttonHeart();
                    //I would like to change data-action from like to unlike
                }else if(action == "unlike"){
                    buttonHeart();
                    //reverse
                }
                output = data.text;
            }
            //alert(output);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Any helps or idea? cheers!

Comment: What about adding something like `$('#btn').attr("data-action","like");` in your branch statements, changing `like` to `unlike` based on the branch it's in?

Comment: Hi, I could try that but everytime when I click the button the attribute is changing just on the first click, so if I click twice nothing change.

Comment: Is the `ajax` call being triggered properly every time? You would need to put that line twice, once in `if(action == "like")` and once in `else if(action == "unlike")`. Also check that the server is returning those two strings exactly

Comment: Cool yep, is working. :)

Comment: Glad it works! Could you clarify what exactly fixed the issue, in case anyone else that stumbles across this question is having that issue?

Comment: Sure! The Javascript is totally correct, the problems it was by php back end though. So i've just made two functions: setLikeByUs($uname, $newsid, $action) and setUnlikeByUs($uname, $newsid, $action), but because I had not use the control if result exists or not the code was saving too many actions in my db. So I wrote down a condition if action is equal to like or unlike, then I've used the query to connect with my db and return the action selected before with json. Hope that's clear, have a good year! :)